# Problem with pointers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers

OK, i have a strange problem. I have this piece of code:

```
int *p;
int test;
p=&test;
```

In Visual C++ express, in my exsisting project, I get this error:

```
missing type specifier - int assumed.
'p' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'char *'
'initializing' : cannot convert from 'char *' to 'int'
```

But when i create new project, same code is fine. Whats the problem please?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the code you presented here.

Comment: Show the actual compilable code - it is likely there is something elsewhere in the project that causes the issue

Comment: That piece of code is incomplete; can you give use the entire program to get more context?

Comment: Sometimes errors in the code before (or after) the line the compiler gives an error on is responsible for causing the error.  For example, if you missed a semicolon or close brace above the code you posted, you might get weird errors on perfectly ordinary looking code (there are no errors in the code you posted).  So maybe post more code.

Answer (score 2):

Something preceding this code may be breaking things (more context might help). Perhaps `test` is a macro that wreaks havoc with the meaning of your code.

Answer (score 1):

If the same code on different projects produces different results, I guess you can assume the problem isn't with the code, but with the project.

I suggest you make a diff between the two project files to have a quick look over what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Have you placed that code inside a function? You cannot write arbitrary C++ code outside of functions.

```
int main() {
    int *p;
    int test;
    p=&test;
}
```